How to pass gradle project properties for snyk test of gradle project
In case we pass environment variable for values of a gradle's project property
say in build.gradle say, we use:
url "https://${nexusDomain}/repository/gvhvid-maven-public"

then running snyk test for a gradle project fails with following error:
ERROR: Gradle Error (short):
> Could not get unknown property 'nexusDomain' for root project
'gvhvid-service' of type org.gradle.api.Project.


because snyk test implicitly runs following command:
/builds/gvhvid/gradlew' snykResolvedDepsJson -q --build-file /builds/gvhvid/build.gradle 
-Dorg.gradle.parallel= -Dorg.gradle.console=plain -I /tmp/tmp-580-SoPWUNy9S4bm--init.gradle 
--no-configuration-cache

Possible solution is to pass the value for project property: nexusDomain via snyk CLI
So, the fix I tried using the SNYK CLI option: --configuration-attributes but that does not seems to be working!

Fix that I found is to pass the value for project property as an environment variables visible to gradle using special prefix ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_ to the build
say:
ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_nexusDomain="gvh.vid.com" 

and then run snyk test worked! ☺️
